# str.translate method is not replacing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with income data from this site: https://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d17/tables/dt17_502.30.asp

Which is quite messy, on the the task on working on is to remove the puntuation fro text like this:

```
'  High school completion\\1\\ ....................................;32,610;;(360);34,840;;(275);34,200;;(943);33,480;;(16);32,970;;(18);32,010;;(#);31,320;;(16);30,900;;(2);30,410;;(4);30,930;;(968);31,830;;(143);\n'
```

But keeping the semicolon, since I'll use it to separate the fields later on.

My aproach to solve is:

1) Replace the #  for "0" since this is been used for missing values

row = row.replace("#","0")

2) Create a dict to map all the puntuacion to None or empty, except for the semicolon.

```
translation = dict((c,"") if c != ";" else (c,";") for c in string.punctuation )
```

3) Make the translation

This is the step is not working:

```
row.translate(translation)
```

retruns the exact same output:

```
'  High school completion\\1\\ ....................................;32,610;;(360);34,840;;(275);34,200;;(943);33,480;;(16);32,970;;(18);32,010;;(0);31,320;;(16);30,900;;(2);30,410;;(4);30,930;;(968);31,830;;(143);\n'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a step—building the translation table using [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
tab = text.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation.replace(';',''), ''))
text.translate(tab)
# '  High school completion1 ;32610;;360;34840;;275;34200;;943;33480;;16;32970;;18;32010;;;31320;;16;30900;;2;30410;;4;30930;;968;31830;;143;\n'
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new table for each string I want to translate? is not clear to me what "text.maketrans" does

Comment: Just to note you can use a dictionary as the input to `str.translate` if you want, you just have to make sure its keys are the `ord` of the characters... eg: `d = {ord(ch): None for ch in string.punctuation if ch != ';'}` - you can then use `text.translate(d)` to get the same results...

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez it creates a table mapping ascii values to their replacements. You can skip the call by building it yourself as JC noted.